# Rules for factors of a composite number

Tags: real-numbers, prime-factorization

Is there any rule that the factors of a composite number must be of the form $n^m$, where $n$ is a real number and $m \ge 1$?

Example 1: the factors of $4$ are : $2^2, 1^1, 4^1$.
Example 2: The factors of $-4$ are $-2^2, -4^1, -1^1$, and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question. Can you give us a couple of examples of what you mean?

Comment: @Billy I have edited!

Comment: Well, first of all, since we're talking about factors, $n$ should be an _integer_, not a real number. Second, when you say the factors of $4$ are $2^2,1^1,4^1$, what does that really _mean_? The prime factorisation of $4$ is $2\cdot2$, which can also be written as $2^2$ if you want (but it's not necessary). The factors of $4$ are $1,2$ and $4$. I don't know what else you could mean.

Comment: If $n$ is a factor, you can always write it in the form $n^m$ by setting $m=1$.  This doesn't seem to get you anywhere, though.

Comment: I just want to know, is it always true that the prime factor of a composite number must have a degree $\ge$ 1?  @Arthur

Comment: You could say that $4$ has a factor of $5^0$, but it's kindof pointless. So we don't do that. So yes, we usually require the exponent to be at least $1$.

Comment: I just wanted to know that. Thanks Arthur. @Arthur